I am trying to use the Azure OpenAI API with my pay-as-you-go subscription tier
I am getting this error:
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: (401) The DocumentModels_AnalyzeDocumentFromStream Operation under Azure AI Document Intelligence 2024-11-30 is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier OpenAI.S0.
Code: 401
Message: The DocumentModels_AnalyzeDocumentFromStream Operation under Azure AI Document Intelligence 2024-11-30 is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier OpenAI.S0.

while running this code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader

file_path = "my_image.jpg"
endpoint = "https://myservice.openai.azure.com/"
key = 'MY_AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY'
loader = AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader(
    api_endpoint=endpoint, api_key=key, file_path=file_path, api_model="prebuilt-layout"
)

documents = loader.load()

print(documents)

Do i miss some info about the pay-as-you-go tier and Azure OpenAI API ?

Please refer this https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/community/document_loaders/langchain_community.document_loaders.doc_intelligence.AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader.html try with all parameters.


The DocumentModels_AnalyzeDocumentFromStream Operation under Azure AI Document Intelligence 2024-11-30 is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier OpenAI.S0.

Initially I also got the same error when I use Azure OpenAI endpoint and key.
Error:

For document intelligence, you need to copy the endpoint and key from Azure Document intelligence service in the portal.
Portal:

Now when I ran the same code with proper endpoint and key it executed successfully.
Code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader

file_path =r"C:\Users\test1.jpg"
endpoint = "https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
key = 'your document intelligence key'
loader = AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader(
    file_path =file_path,api_endpoint=endpoint, api_key=key,  api_model="prebuilt-layout"
)

documents = loader.load()

print(documents)

Output:
[Document(metadata={'apiVersion': '2024-11-30', 'modelId': 'prebuilt-layout', 'stringIndexType': 'textElements', 'content': '', 'pages': [{'pageNumber': 1, 'angle': 0, 'width': 640, 'height': 426, 'unit': 'pixel', 'words': [], 'lines': [], 'spans': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 0}]}], 'tables': [], 'contentFormat': 'markdown'}, page_content='')]


Reference:
AzureAIDocumentIntelligenceLoader —  LangChain documentation

First: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: this is a simple mistake that could have been explained in a comment. There is no specific programming error - just the wrong key. No need for a long answer to correct something like this.
